# Cannot downgrade from CentOS 7.6 to 7.5

Tags: centos, linux-kernel

I am trying to downgrade my CentOS 7.6 to the previous minor release 7.5. I am currently on kernel version `3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64`. For the downgrade I need to install kernel version `3.10.0-862` (7.5 release).

But my current mirror cannot find the kernel package required:

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum list kernel-3.10.0-862*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: www.mirrorservice.org
 * extras: mirror.econdc.com
 * updates: mirror.econdc.com
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

I also tried to enable the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo` repo but without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS [only supports the latest point release](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-dcca41e9a3d5ac4c6d900a991990fd11930867d6), and moves older binaries to its vault a few weeks after each point release. You’ll find [CentOS 7.5 binaries here](http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/), and you can download the kernel [manually](http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/).

I’m surprised you’d need an older kernel, 3.10.0-957.10.1 should be fully backwards-compatible with 3.10.0-862.

Comment: To answer your question regarding the need for an older kernel, I am having to do this right now, for IBM's QRadar CE. The installer fails, noting that CentOS 7.6 is installed, but that it requires CentOS or RHEL 7.5. I'm sure with a little tweaking of the script, this could be resolved, but since it essentially requires its own OS dedicated to it (and once installed, it cannot be uninstalled or disabled, as made clear by IBM), it's just easier to give it exactly what it wants. I know there are other applications out there that lock their installation to wanting a specific release as well

Comment: This is what I have find from IBM [QRadar CE 7.3.1 installation Guide on RHEL Server 7.5/7.6][https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/477564/qradar-ce-731-installation-guide-on-rhel-server-75-1/]

Here is the core steps mentioned in the link. Basically it is modifying the checking function to look for 7.6.

     mkdir /tmp/qradar-7.6
     cp -R /media/cdrom/* /tmp/qradar-7.6
     sed -i 's/release 7.5/release 7.6/g' /tmp/qradar-7.6/inc/setup.funcs
     /tmp/qradar-7.6/setup